# angular : unable to set the object using @input getter and setter

Tags: angular

I am basically trying to convert the object to an array and bind it to kendo-dropdown control. When I do direct @Input bind, the dropdown binds but gives an error saying that data.map is not supported. Basically, the dropdown needs an array object. When I use the getter and setter property for @Input, I am getting fundclass as undefined. Could somebody tell me what the problem is

```
get fundclass(): any {
    return this._fundclass;
}

@Input()
set fundclass(fundclass: any) {
    if (this.fundclass !== undefined ) {
        this._fundclass =  Object.keys(this.fundclass).map(key => ({type: key, value: this.fundclass[key]}));
    }
}
```

JSON - Just to be clear, I have done a JSON.parse of the object during debugging just to show what the internal structure of the object looks like

```
"[{"FundClassId":13714,"FundClass":"Class D"},{"FundClassId":13717,"FundClass":"Class B"},{"FundClassId":13713,"FundClass":"Class A"},{"FundClassId":13716,"FundClass":"Class B1"},{"FundClassId":13715,"FundClass":"Class C"}]"
```

HTML

```
<kendo-dropdownlist style="width:170px" [data]="fundclass" [filterable]="false"
            [(ngModel)]="fundclass" textField="FundClass" [valuePrimitive]="true"
            valueField="FundClassId"  (valueChange)="flashClassChanged($event)"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Updated code and UI based on previous suggestions. The issue here is that I cant see the display values all i see is underlying value which is the value of the id

```
_fundclass: any;

      get fundclass(): any {
        return this._fundclass;
      }

      @Input()
      set fundclass(fundclass: any) {
        if (fundclass !== undefined ) {
         this._fundclass =  Object.keys(fundclass).map(key => ({text: key, value: fundclass[key]}));
        }
      }
```

Markup

```
<kendo-dropdownlist style="width:170px" [data]="fundclass" [filterable]="false"
            [(ngModel)]="fundclass" textField="key" [valuePrimitive]="true"
            valueField="fundclass[key]"  (valueChange)="flashClassChanged($event)"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Comment: You are not using the `fundclass` that you receive in setter anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.fundclass` which refers to object property so remove that `this` part to get the function argument.

```
@Input()
set fundclass(fundclass: any) {
  if (fundclass !== undefined ) {
  //--^^^^^^^^--- here
     this._fundclass =  Object.keys(fundclass).map(key => ({text: key, value: fundclass[key]}));
     // ---------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----- here
  }
}
```

---

You can even use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to simplify your code.

```
@Input()
set fundclass(fundclass: any) {
  if (fundclass !== undefined ) {
     this._fundclass =  Object.entries(fundclass).map(([text, value]) => ({text, value}));
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE :** Problem lies in the model binding you are using the same model while binding change it to something else, otherwise when you changing the value the selected value will be set as `_fundclass` property value but dropdown data should be an array.

**Template :**

```
<kendo-dropdownlist style="width:170px" [data]="fundclass" [filterable]="false"
        [(ngModel)]="fundclass1" textField="FundClass" [valuePrimitive]="true"
        valueField="FundClassId"  (valueChange)="flashClassChanged($event)"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

**TS :**

```
_fundclass:any;
fundclass1:any;

get fundclass(): any {
    return this._fundclass;
}

@Input()
set fundclass(fundclass: any) {
    if (this.fundclass !== undefined ) {
        this._fundclass =  Object.keys(this.fundclass).map(key => ({type: key, value: this.fundclass[key]}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Its now not undefined but the combo boxes doest show data. I can see [object][object]. Does my markup need to change. I tried textField="fundclass[key]" and  valueField="key"

Comment: @Tom : try `{text: key, value: fundclass[key]}` ... For text you need to set text property not type....

Comment: I tried that. And changed my markup to textField="key" and  valueField="fundclass[key]". What I am seeing is the underlying value in the dropdown and not the display test. For example I am seeing 0,1,2 in the drop down

Comment: @Tom :  can u share value of `fundclass`

Comment: Updated how the JSON looks like

Comment: @Tom : simply try `this._fundclass = fundclass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191712/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-tom).